# Can a Bard use Glyph of Warding even though they do not "prepare" spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

**Can a Bard use Glyph of Warding even though they do not "prepare" spells?**

In looking at the reasonable boundaries of using *Glyph of Warding* in the game, I came across a dilemma in the wording of the spell when it comes to classes that do not have "prepared spells", but have "known spells instead.

*Glyph of Warding* says that "you can store a prepared spell", however this wording becomes an issue when interpreting whether a Bard can or cannot use this spell.

A bard does not per se "prepare" their spells. Yet, the spell is listed in the Bard Spells section in the *Player's Handbook* (p.207). Hrumpf! It is listed as a Bard spell which normally suggest that **it is intended to be used by a Bard** as part of their magical repertoire, but the wording needs clarification.

So, for the purposes of interpreting the wording in *Glyph of Warding*, can we equate "prepared spell" with "known spell", which would mean the Bard can actually use this spell?

> **Spell Glyph.** You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell
>   must target a single creature or an area. The spell being stored has
>   no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is
>   triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell has a target, it
>   targets the creature that triggered the glyph. If the spell affects an
>   area, the area is centered on that creature. If the spell summons
>   hostile creatures or creates harmful objects or traps, they appear as
>   close as possible to the intruder and attack it. If the spell requires
>   concentration, it lasts until the end of its full duration.  (PHB
>   p.245)

Special thanks to BBeast for kindly mentioning this issue in his answer to: 
[Can you store Hex in a Glyph of Warding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164224/can-you-store-hex-in-a-glyph-of-warding)

Comment: I agree its not explicitly spelled out that "known spells" are effectively "always prepared spells", but the question linked as the duplicate gives this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you @PJRZ that is exactly what I was looking for. This is a helpful answer for anyone who multi-classes and wishes to use a "known spell" from a class like a Warlock or Ranger. Thanks again. :)