# What happens when a Held ooze splits?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

I'd created a homebrew ooze monster with the same Split reaction that Black Puddings have. A PC cast Hold Monster on it before it was hit with any attack that would split it, so what would happen after it was cut in half? Would one of the halves still have the Hold spell on it, both of them or neither?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate because I felt [the one I marked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56705) addresses/answers your own. If you feel this is not the case feel free to [edit] and explain why and your question will get reopened. That all said, hello and welcome to the site! Take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and you can visit the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks Medix, that question does cover it.